# OpenLdap proxy CN case-sensitive

Tags: proxy, ldap, openldap

I am having a web app which needs to cache a notes ldap. For that the IT installed Openldap which will be queried from the web app. Basically OpenLdap Proxy.
now CN=My User, O=Corp
comes over as cn=My User, o=Corp...
(notice the case CN vs. cn, etc)

Can I adjust something in slapd.conf that tells my mapping to be case-sensitive?

Comment: You'd probably have more luck and answers on Serverfault.com where the SysAdmins hang out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are case-insensitive by design, according to the specification, see [RFC 4514](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514) and [RFC 4512](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514), more specifically, [section 1.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-1.4):

> Short names, also known as descriptors, are used as more readable aliases for object identifiers.  Short names are case insensitive and conform to the ABNF:
>
> ```
>   descr = keystring
> ```

It's not clear what you're trying to do with your application, but libraries that handle such distinguished names should be able to handle that in theory.