# ldap proxy CN case-sensitive

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

Im trying to query AD info from this [openLDAP-Proxy](https://github.com/netaskd/ldap-ad-proxy), but the responses are not case sensitive, therefore instead of getting

```
member: CN=User,OU=Group,DC=Base,DC=local
```

i get as a response

```
member: cn=User,ou=Group,dc=Base,dc=local
```

And so im unable to use correctly the proxy with an application (Shibboleth IDP)

I've seen [theres already a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451254/openldap-proxy-cn-case-sensitive) but the response doesnt help

Comment: Sorry "the response doesnt help" but is is a fact.

Comment: @jwilleke yeah so what can i do? if you know why it is, could you at least hint me on how to approach it?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the specific problem you're trying to resolve? As the linked response indicates, those fields are required to be case-insensitive. How is the difference in case causing a problem?

Comment: Doesn't work with the application why? All LDAP attributes are case-insensitive by default.

Answer (score 1):

From LDAP, the entry:

```
member: CN=User,OU=Group,DC=Base,DC=local 
AND 
member: cn=User,ou=Group,dc=Base,dc=local
```

Are the same entries. There is no way to distinguish one from the other.

You could when they are returned do something like UPPERCASE(member: cn=User,ou=Group,dc=Base,dc=local)